# Explain Chisel3 <> vs := ?

Tags: riscv, chisel

I know there has been some debate about support/meaning/usage of Chisel3 's <> and := operators for bulk connecting groups of signals.

Can someone provide, or point me to a good reference for:

- what exactly does each do
- when should I use one and not the other

Answer (score 0):

Operator `<>` is used for bulk bundle connections. See [here](https://github.com/freechipsproject/chisel3/wiki/Interfaces-Bulk-Connections) for additional information.  Operator `:=` is used for individual nets/buses.